# How to correctly clean the Lacquer from bed?

Tags: heated-bed, creality-ender-3, bed

How can I correctly clean the lacquer from bed printer?

I have used some ethylic alcohol (ethanol) to help cleaning

But what is the best way to do it?

[image]

Comment: I guess you are implying that the "lacquer" you talk about is not the original surface layer, but residue build-up by depositing a print adhesive containing PolyVinylPyrrolidone (glue stick ingredient) or PolyVinylAcetate (hairspray or 3D print spray ingredient)?

Comment: Please comment on the bed deposition residue, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The Ender 3 does not come with a lacquered surface at all.The bed should have a rough build surface that is a clone of the BuildTak build surface. It is *intended* to be rough and satin-gloss in its native state. I do not remember if there was a thin protective plastic foil on my Ender-3 bed on delivery, but if there was, it should have been removed during assembly.

A BuildTak surface can be easily cleaned with isopropyl or ethyl alcohol of grease and fingerprints. The odd discoloration at the edges seems to be a layer of grease and dust, which can be easily cleaned away by soaking it in Isopropyl alcohol and then wiped with a microfiber cloth.

If the bed surface is destroyed by chipping holes into it, sanding it or otherwise ruining it (like melting plastic rap into it), you will need to replace it. Replacement surfaces come about 5 bucks on Amazon. Doing this, you might find [How to clean up my buildpate for a new build surface?](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/7960/how-to-clean-up-my-buildpate-for-a-new-build-surface) helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The "lacquer" you are referring to is assumed to be the discoloured parts of the heat bed, not the original surface layer of the heat bed. The discoloured parts of the heatbed are most probably caused by residue build-up.

If this residue build-up is caused by depositing a print adhesive containing PolyVinylPyrrolidone (glue stick ingredient) or PolyVinylAcetate (hairspray or 3D print spray ingredient), you can simply wash is of with water using a wet hand-warm towel or a sponge. Both constituents are dissolvable in water.

I do this frequently on non-removable aluminium heat beds (using moist kitchen towel) or removable glass bed (rinse off in the sink).